# NSTimer does not count down in while loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

```
int maximumMinute;

NSTimer *timer;

- (void)startTimer: (int) minute {
maximumMinute = minute;
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(countDown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

- (void)countDown {

maximumMinute -= 1;
self.timerLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", maximumMinute];
if (maximumMinute == 0) {
    [timer invalidate];
}
}
```

This is my timer code and i just start the timer in viewDidLoad

i have this method called when some view is clicked for just testing.

```
   -(void)clickSomthing: (UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    int i = 0;
while ([timer isValid])
{
    NSLog(@"timer valid");
}
```

Firstly, when the view is loaded, the timer count is fired and i can see the time count down actually but when i click any view associated with the method "clickSomething" the timer does not count down actually it stops.

What i really want to do is that i want the timer keep going on until it reaches zero regardless of while or for loop. Actually, I am trying to stop my game based on the timer but the game does need some while loop and for loop that would take a while.

Comment: You are locking the main thread of your application with the while loop, with it the whole app and the timer.

Comment: How can i fix it? or any suggestion for what i want to do??

Answer (score 0):

Your code lock the main thread (you never should do this) you should use GCD - Grand Central Dispatch to let the countdown in background while the user keep using the app.

```
-(void)clickSomthing: (UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{

        int countDown = 10; // This is the countdown time
        BOOL letTheCountDown = TRUE;
        while (letTheCountDown) {
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0]; // Count second by second
            countDown--;
            NSLog(@"countDown %i",countDown);

            if (countDown == 0) {
                letTheCountDown = FALSE;                                    
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    // Do something in main thread here. Ex: alert
                    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Time is Over" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [alert show];
                });
            }

        }

    });

}
```